# Is it possible to retrieve data from Office365 - Exchange Online/Azure using LDAP?

Tags: azure, ldap, office365

We do branding and signatures for outgoing mail and are starting to receive a lot of queries for data sync to populate signatures from Exchange Online on Office365.

Is there a way to retrieve this data from Azure using LDAP, like you can from Active Directory on Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you can get the information you need via LDAP:

> There are several interfaces exposed for Azure AD but AAD doesn't support LDAP externally.

[(source)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2015/01/05/azure-active-directory-for-the-old-school-ad-admin.aspx)

Office 365 and Azure AD both support REST APIs for accessing data:

- [Office 365 REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog)
- [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx)